# Lost admin/backend login form in Joomla

Tags: forms, authentication, admin, backend

I lost my administrator log-in form from back-end. Can any one please help to recover it?

Comment: no, we can't help you, sorry.

Comment: did not get you. what do u mean by sofa? @Mike W

Answer (score 1):

You have to log in your database (via phpmyadmin) and run this query (workig for joomla version 2.5 and 3):

```
INSERT INTO `jos31_users`
   (`name`, `username`, `password`, `params`)
VALUES ('Administrator2', 'admin2',
    'd2064d358136996bd22421584a7cb33e:trd7TvKHx6dMeoMmBVxYmg0vuXEA4199', '');
INSERT INTO `jos31_user_usergroup_map` (`user_id`,`group_id`)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'8');
```

* You have to change `jos31_` with your database table prefix.

Then you could log in to your joomla with username: "admin2" and password "secret".

[Here is the complete tutorial how you could recover admin password in joomla](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_or_reset_your_admin_password%3F).

Good Luck!