# Joomla Login doesn't work - No error message

Tags: session, joomla, authentication

I have an issue, I can't login anymore in my Joomla installation.
I googled the issue and found many similar questions and so on, so I tried to check my tables over phpmyadmin an look if the plg_user_joomla plugin was disabled (http://www.itoctopus.com/login-to-joomla-administrator-not-working-and-no-error-is-displayed) --> IT WAS. I fixed the '0' to an '1' but i still can't login. (auth-modules and plugins are enabled now, I've checked this)

After that I've read some solutions where the "session folder" is not writeable, but my sessions are saved in the DB, so I think its not the problem.

And now I have no idea what to do, so I can login again in my joomla.

my system:
--shared hosting-- only installed two components (acymailing and hikashop)

configuration.php:
Code:

```
<?php
class JConfig {
   public $offline = '1';
   public $offline_message = 'Diese Website ist zurzeit im Wartungsmodus.<br />Bitte spaeter wiederkommen.';
   public $display_offline_message = '1';
   public $offline_image = '';
   public $sitename = 'Bones;
   public $editor = 'tinymce';
   public $captcha = '0';
   public $list_limit = '20';
   public $access = '1';
   public $debug = '1';
   public $debug_lang = '0';
   public $dbtype = 'mysqli';
   public $host = 'localhost';
   public $user = 'USRXXX';
   public $password = 'SECRET_PASSWORD';
   public $db = 'usr_USRXXX_1';
   public $dbprefix = 'vfshj_';
   public $live_site = '';
   public $secret = 'SECRET';
   public $gzip = '0';
   public $error_reporting = 'default';
   public $helpurl = 'http://help.joomla.org/proxy/index.php?option=com_help&keyref=Help{major}{minor}:{keyref}';
   public $ftp_host = '';
   public $ftp_port = '';
   public $ftp_user = '';
   public $ftp_pass = '';
   public $ftp_root = '';
   public $ftp_enable = '0';
   public $offset = 'Europe/Berlin';
   public $mailonline = '1';
   public $mailer = 'mail';
   public $mailfrom = 'mymail@google.com';
   public $fromname = 'Bones';
   public $sendmail = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
   public $smtpauth = '0';
   public $smtpuser = '';
   public $smtppass = '';
   public $smtphost = 'localhost';
   public $smtpsecure = 'none';
   public $smtpport = '25';
   public $caching = '0';
   public $cache_handler = 'file';
   public $cachetime = '15';
   public $MetaDesc = '';
   public $MetaKeys = '';
   public $MetaTitle = '1';
   public $MetaAuthor = '1';
   public $MetaVersion = '0';
   public $robots = '';
   public $sef = '1';
   public $sef_rewrite = '1';
   public $sef_suffix = '1';
   public $unicodeslugs = '0';
   public $feed_limit = '10';
   public $log_path = '/var/www/USRXXX/html/logs';
   public $tmp_path = '/var/www/USRXXX/html/tmp';
   public $lifetime = '15';
   public $session_handler = 'database';
   public $memcache_persist = '1';
   public $memcache_compress = '0';
   public $memcache_server_host = 'localhost';
   public $memcache_server_port = '11211';
   public $memcached_persist = '1';
   public $memcached_compress = '0';
   public $memcached_server_host = 'localhost';
   public $memcached_server_port = '11211';
   public $proxy_enable = '0';
   public $proxy_host = '';
   public $proxy_port = '';
   public $proxy_user = '';
   public $proxy_pass = '';
   public $MetaRights = '';
   public $sitename_pagetitles = '2';
   public $force_ssl = '0';
   public $session_memcache_server_host = 'localhost';
   public $session_memcache_server_port = '11211';
   public $session_memcached_server_host = 'localhost';
   public $session_memcached_server_port = '11211';
   public $frontediting = '1';
   public $feed_email = 'author';
   public $cookie_domain = 'bone_';
   public $cookie_path = '';
   public $asset_id = '1';
}
```

if you want to try and read the debug output:
http://bonesetterband.de/administrator/index.php

a test user is:
admin2 : secret

### (I'm really sure, this one is correct !)

I think it's something with the session and cookie management, but I really don't know how and why.

Comment: Please try these steps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25738030/3834042

Comment: i did already, thats why the testuser listet above the config.php here is "a test user is: admin2 : secret" ;-)

Comment: You could download latest joomla upgrade package and override all files to make sure that there isn't something altered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it,

i accidentally set a cookie domain in the config, but i thought about a cookie pre-fix, but thats no prefix, its the cookie domain. so the session cookie will be set to a domain like "bone_" which is not my domain ;D

so no phpssid will be transmitted.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but looking in my configuration.php the $cookie_domain was already set to ''.

But I solved the problem setting the $cookie_path to '' (I wrongly set it to the relative path of my site...).

Regards